# Hide the bottom line and change the style of the selected element Drowdown_button2

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I need your help. I'm using `dropdown_button2` from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) but I've run into a few issues that I can't resolve. **First mistake**: how to change the text style of the selected element? I need the text that displays the selected item to be larger. The **second mistake**: you need to remove the bottom line, which is displayed under the selected element, when the element is not selected, there is no line, only the element is selected - the line appears. Below I have attached screenshots of what I have now and what I need to get in the end. I would appreciate your help.

**dropdown**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 120,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          bottom: selectedValue != null
              ? const BorderSide(
                  color: constants.Colors.white,
                )
              : BorderSide.none,
        ),
      ),
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2(
          hint: const Text(
            'Select',
            style: constants.Styles.bigBookTextStyleWhite,
          ),
          items: widget.items
              .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: item,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            if (item == selectedValue)
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 0,
                              ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                item,
                                style: constants.Styles.smallTextStyleWhite,
                              ),
                            ),
                            if (item == selectedValue)
                              const Icon(
                                Icons.check,
                                color: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                              ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList(),
          value: selectedValue,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = value as String;
            });
          },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.arrowDropdown),
          iconSize: 21,
          buttonHeight: 27,
          buttonElevation: 1,
          itemHeight: 47,
          dropdownMaxHeight: 191,
          dropdownWidth: 140,
          dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            border: Border.all(
              color: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
            ),
            color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
          ),
          selectedItemBuilder: (context) {
            return widget.items.map((item) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  item,
                  style: constants.Styles.smallTextStyleWhite,
                ),
              );
            }).toList();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**at the moment I have**

[image]

**should be the result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To change text style of the selected element use `selectedItemBuilder`. It's responsible for how the selected item will be displayed on button.
2. The bottom line under the selected element is shown by the `decoration` parameter you're using in the main `Container` widget. Remove it and bottom line should be gone.